# Balanceo por porcentaje?

Tags: algoritmos, diagrama-de-flujo

Buenas tardes Estimados,

El problema en si no es de codificación si no mas bien de definir bien un proceso para luego a codificarlo.

Tengo la presente situación, debo referir o delegar tareas a x o y webService de acuerdo a un porcentaje definido.  Ejemplo :

Enviar 80 % de las peticiones al webService "X" y el 20 % al webService "Y" ese porcentaje debe ser configurable, pero no es lo que me aqueja en este momento. No tengo claro como proceder para hacer optimo ese "Balanceo".

Tengo pensado especificar un umbral minimo de peticiones ejemplo 10 y de allí comenzar a contar 8 peticiones para "X" y 2 peticiones para "Y" o lo contrario para cubrir primero el de menor porcentaje y luego el de mayor porcentaje.

Como me recomiendan realizar este tipo de balanceo.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema, para mi, es que si la decisión la tomás en el programa que realiza las llamadas no vas a tener la cantidad de peticiones que se hicieron para poder decidir a quien llamar.

Para esto yo utilizaría un valor aleatorio entre 0 y 1, si el valor es menor a .8 enviás la petición al servicio x, si es mayor o igual a .8 la enviás la servicio y.

Esta forma de "balanceo" la utilizamos en varios lugares de nuestros códigos y, dentro de todo, funcionan bien.

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, por lo que entiendo seria un ramdom podria ser de tipo float y hacer la validacion cierto ???

Comment: Exacto, esa es la idea.